# Symfony 5.2 workflow component not found

Tags: php, symfony, workflow

- I did all the steps of [Symfony the fast track Step 19.3](https://symfony.com/doc/current/the-fast-track/en/19-workflow.html#using-a-workflow)

  - When running the page to get a conference I get The following error

> Cannot autowire service "App\MessageHandler\CommentMessageHandler": argument "$workflow" of method "__construct()" references interface "Symfony\Component\Workflow\WorkflowInterface" but no such service exists. You should maybe alias this interface to the existing "state_machine.comment" service.

- I installed the Workflow service using composer, it is located at *guestbook/vendor/symfony/workflow/WorkflowInterface.php* under the namespace *Symfony\Component\Workflow;*
- The CommentMessageHandler whose constructor cannot find the WorkflowInterface is the following:

```php
<?php
namespace App\MessageHandler;

use Symfony\Component\Messenger\Handler\MessageHandlerInterface;
use App\Repository\CommentRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Messenger\MessageBusInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Workflow\WorkflowInterface;
use App\SpamChecker;
use App\Message\CommentMessage;

class CommentMessageHandler implements MessageHandlerInterface
{
    private $spamChecker;
    private $entityManager;
    private $commentRepository;
    private $bus;
    private $workflow;
    private $logger;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, SpamChecker $spamChecker, CommentRepository $commentRepository,
    MessageBusInterface $bus, WorkflowInterface $workflow, LoggerInterface $logger = null)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        $this->spamChecker = $spamChecker;
        $this->commentRepository = $commentRepository;
        $this->bus = $bus;
        $this->workflow = $workflow;
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function __invoke(CommentMessage $message)
    {
        $comment = $this->commentRepository->find($message->getId());
        if (!$comment){
            return;
        }

        /*if (2 == $this->spamChecker->getSpamScore($comment, $message->getContext()))
        {
            $comment->setState('spam');
        } else {
            $comment->setState('published');
        }

        $this->entityManager->flush();*/
        if($this->workflow->can($comment, 'accept')){ //Je suis au premier niveau du Workflow
            //$score = $this->spamChecker->getSpamScore($comment, $message->getContext());
            $score = 2;
            $transition = 'accept';
            if (2 == $score){
                $transition = 'reject_spam';
            } else if ( 1 == $score){
                $transition = 'might_be_spam';
            }
            $this->workflow->apply($comment, $transition);
            $this->entity->flush();

            $this->bus->dispatch($message);
        } 
        elseif($this->workflow->can($comment, 'publish') || $this->workflow->can($comment, 'publish_ham')) {
            $this->workflow->apply($comment, $this->workflow->can($comment, 'publish') ? 'publish': 'publish_ham');
            $this->entity->flush();
        }
        elseif($this->logger)  {
            $this->logger->debug('Dropping comment message', ['comment' => $comment->getId(), 'state' => $comment->getState()]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer in [using alias for defining autowiring](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/service_container/autowiring.html#using-aliases-to-enable-autowiring)
. I then added to the service.yaml

```yaml
services:
    .........................
   Symfony\Component\Workflow\WorkflowInterface:'@state_machine.comment'
```

Comment: I usaly use the Registry for this `Symfony\Component\Workflow\Registry`  via `$stateMachine = $registry->get(new CommentMessage())` for example